# How to access a constant inside of a if statement in React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter

I'm using react/redux. I'm bringing in an array from my database and setting it as one of my redux states. Inside of one of my components, I am filtering through that array to create a new array. But before I can do that, I have to check if the redux states have been loaded so that the array I am attempting to filter does not come out as "null." As a solution, I use a if statement to check if the states are loaded. The new filtered array inside of the if statement is valid and returns what I want (because I console logged it inside the if statement). However, I cannot access the new filtered array because it's inside of the if statement... How can I get around this?

What I've tried:

1. create an empty state using useState and setting the new array as the state.
   Issue: I get re-rendering error becasue the new state forces rerendering of the component, which goes through the if-statement again, which rerenders the state again.. repeat...

My alternative solution:
I can pass down my redux states for conditioning through my action file so I can filter inside of there instead of my component. But I'm sure there is a simpler way to just access my new filtered array inside of the component..

Thank you for your time

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import { getAllSubjects } from "../../actions/subjects";

import '../styles/Dashboard.scss';


const Dashboard = ({
  getAllSubjects,
  auth: { user },
  subjects: { subjects, loading },
}) => {

    const [dashSub, setDashSub] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllSubjects(user);
  }, []);



  // Create new array of subjects to display
  if (subjects && !loading && user) {
    const dashboardSubjects = subjects.filter(function (e) {
      if (user.status === "Admin" || user.status === "Instructor") {
        return e.instructorSubjects === user.instructorSubjects;
      } else {
        return e.studentSubjects === user.studentSubjects;
      }
    });

    console.log(dashboardSubjects)
  }


  return loading && subjects === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <div className="dashboard">
        {dashboardSubjects && dashboardSubjects.map((subject) => {
            return (
                <ul>

                </ul>
            )
        })}
    </div>
  );
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getAllSubjects: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  subjects: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  subjects: state.subjects,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getAllSubjects })(Dashboard);
```

Comment: sorry about that! sort of new to posting questions on stackoverflow and I was having issues copy and pasting the code! will keep it mind for the future!

Comment: @Jae If you figure it out, please feel free to edit your current question. By putting it as text, we can copy paste it ourselves, and it's much easier for us to solve your problem when we can manipulate the code as we like, rather than just passively looking at unrunnable text with unfamiliar syntax highlighting

Comment: Thank you for your criticisms! I've edited the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the variable just before the if statement. If it enters the if statement, assign the filtered array to it. If not, it remains undefined.

```
let dashboardSubjects;
if (subjects && !loading && user) {
  dashboardSubjects = subjects.filter(function (e) {
    if (user.status === "Admin" || user.status === "Instructor") {
      return e.instructorSubjects === user.instructorSubjects;
    } else {
      return e.studentSubjects === user.studentSubjects;
    }
  });

  console.log(dashboardSubjects);
}
```

If subjects is a large array, you may want to consider memoizing this, so you only calculate it when something changes, rather than on every render:

```
let dashboardSubjects = useMemo(() => {
  if (subjects && !loading && user) {
    return subjects.filter(function (e) {
      if (user.status === "Admin" || user.status === "Instructor") {
        return e.instructorSubjects === user.instructorSubjects;
      } else {
        return e.studentSubjects === user.studentSubjects;
      }
    });
  } else {
    return undefined;
  }
}, [subjects, loading, user]);
```

Comment: I can't believe I haven't thought of that. Thank you so much!! This will help me now and for the future. :)